# Add Conditions to Password Validation JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to add some further validation to this password code. I created a if statement where if any of the conditions fail, the condition that failed will print out the relevant message. I tried adding validation for:

- Password must have 1 Digit (0-9)
- Password must have 1 UpperCase (A-Z)
- Password must have 1 LowerCase (a-z)

Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function check_form() {
    var passw = document.getElementById('password-input-0').value;
    var passw2 = document.getElementById('password-input-1').value;
    var letter = /[a-zA-Z]/;
    var number = /[0-9]/;

    if (passw.length < 6 || passw != passw2 || !letter.test(passw) || !number.test(passw)) {
        if (passw.length < 6) {
            alert("Please make sure password is longer than 6 characters.")
            return false;
        }
        if (passw != passw2) {
            alert("Please make sure passwords match.")
            return false;
        }
        if (!letter.test(passw)) {
            alert("Please make sure Password Includes an UpperCase and LowerCase character")
            return false;
        }
        if (!number.test(passw)) {
            alert("Please make sure Password Includes a Digit")
            return false;
        }

        /*email test*/
        var email = document.getElementById('email-input-0').value;
        var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
        if (!filter.test(email)) {
            alert('Please provide a valid email address');
            form.email.focus;
            return false;
        }


        return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

This code doesn't seem to work and being an inexperience JS programmer I'm not sure why it's not working. I've left the email-validation just to make sure the fix doesn't interfere with it. Thanks for reading!

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3kPkQ/)

Comment: Uh... I think this code `if(passw.length < 6 || passw != passw2 || !letter.test(passw) || !number.test(passw) ) {...}` is kinda redundant, because you're checking again inside it.

Comment: Please post a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your code so we can easier/faster take a look at it

Comment: @user3241019 fiddle is there, but I did add it late

Comment: @dunli how would you recommend doing it? Would it be better to split it all up into individual If statements?

Comment: Ah yes thanks, I was actually working on a new one for you

Comment: @user3241019 thanks! Soon as I posted it I knew someone would ask for a fiddle so I quickly added it... obv not quick enough!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were a few problems in your code. First, you were missing a couple of `}` close braces - for example the end of your first main `if` clause.

Secondly, the character check was a bit bugged - it checks both uppercase and lowercase in the same check, so passwords that shouldn't be valid got through.

I have updated the fiddle and it now contains the right code, solving both problems: http://jsfiddle.net/3kPkQ/3/

```
function check_form()
{
var passw = document.getElementById('password-input-0').value;
var passw2 = document.getElementById('password-input-1').value;
var letter = /[a-z]/;
var upper  =/[A-Z]/;
var number = /[0-9]/;

if(passw.length < 6 || passw != passw2 || !letter.test(passw) || !number.test(passw) || !upper.test(passw)) {
  if(passw.length<6){
    alert("Please make sure password is longer than 6 characters.")
    return false;
  }
  if(passw != passw2){
    alert("Please make sure passwords match.")
    return false;
  }
  if(!letter.test(passw)){
    alert("Please make sure password includes a lowercase letter.")
    return false;
  }
  if(!number.test(passw)){
    alert("Please make sure Password Includes a Digit")
    return false;     
  }
  if(!upper.test(passw)) {
    alert("Please make sure password includes an uppercase letter.");
    return false;
  }
}

/*email test*/
var email = document.getElementById('email-input-0').value;
var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
if (!filter.test(email)) {
  alert('Please provide a valid email address');
  form.email.focus;
  return false;
}


return true;
}
```

That should work - fixes the second problem in @faby's answer too.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Can't believe I missed the `}`!! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/3kPkQ/5/

```
   function check_form()
{
var passw = document.getElementById('password-input-0').value;
var passw2 = document.getElementById('password-input-1').value;
var letter = /[a-z]/;
 var letterUp= /[A-Z]/;
var number = /[0-9]/;

if(passw.length < 6 || passw != passw2 || !letter.test(passw) || !number.test(passw) ) {
      if(passw.length<6){
      alert("Please make sure password is longer than 6 characters.")
      return false;
      }
      if(passw != passw2){
      alert("Please make sure passwords match.")
      return false;
      }
      if(!letter.test(passw) || !letterUp.test(passw)){
      alert("Please make sure Password Includes an UpperCase and LowerCase character")
      return false;
      }
      if(!number.test(passw)){
      alert("Please make sure Password Includes a Digit")
      return false;     
  }

  /*email test*/
var email = document.getElementById('email-input-0').value;
var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  if (!filter.test(email)) {
     alert('Please provide a valid email address');
     form.email.focus;
     return false;
}


return true;
}
}
```

html

```
<input type="text" id="password-input-0"/>
<input type="text" id="password-input-1"/>
<input type="button" value="clickme" id="password-input-2" onclick="check_form()"/>
```

Comment: I'll test this now on the live website

Comment: It works OK, but if you put in `helloworld9` as the password it won't ask you to include an uppercase letter, or vice versa for `HELLOWORLD9`.

Comment: update.. try now and let me know. I'm sorry I didn't saw that you had already a correct answer.