# if else statement beginner fix

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new in javascript and trying some new things. I have input password and need to merge it with function. Function if working well but only without password and now I need to add there static password. If password is good I want to use that function. If password is bad I want to show alert bad password

```js
var inputPass = document.getElementById('pass');
var pass = "user";

if (inputPass.value === pass) {

  function render() {
  
    var encodedString = '[[HTML_BASE64]]';

    function b64DecodeUnicode(str) {
      return decodeURIComponent(atob(str).split('').map(function(c) {
        return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
      }).join(''));
    }
  }

  document.write(b64DecodeUnicode(encodedString));

} else(alert("wrong pass"));
```

```html
<input type="password" class="pass" id="pass">
<button class="login" onclick="render()">Login</button>
```

Comment: You have some odd wrapping of functions inside each other, but the first thing to look at is that `====` is not a valid operator in JS, I think you are looking for either 2 or 3 `=` (For relaxed type equals, or strict type equals, respectively), not 4.

Comment: you can check this implementation as well:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24055785/add-conditions-to-password-validation-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to make sure to divide the functions according to their usefulness. Second, you should check the javascript guidelines so that you don't make mistakes like comparison.

```
function render(){
var inputPass= document.getElementById('pass');
var pass="user";
if(inputPass.value==="heslo"){
    var encodedString = '[[HTML_BASE64]]';
    document.write(b64DecodeUnicode(encodedString));
}else{
    alert("wrong pass");
}
```

}

```
function b64DecodeUnicode(str) {
  return decodeURIComponent(atob(str).split('').map(function(c) {
    return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
  }).join(''));
}

<input type="password" class="pass" id="pass"/>
<button class="login" onclick="render()">Login</button>
```

Comment: Please add some information to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no `====` operator. Use `==` or `===`.

Second, `heslo` should be a string `'heslo'`. Or maybe you have `heslo` defined somewhere, but I don't see it.

Try replacing this:

```
inputPass.value ==== heslo
```

With this:

```
inputPass.value == 'heslo'
```

Comment: heslo was wrong by me...should be pass...it's defined higher...I edited now you can see it right

Answer (score 0):

From my observation, there are lots of things wrong with this code, not sure what you are trying to achieve with the code but I tried arranging them for you

```
var inputPass = document.getElementById('pass');
var pass = "user";
function render() {
    if (inputPass.value === pass) {
    var encodedString = '[[HTML_BASE64]]';
    let  b64DecodeUnicode= function(str) {
       return decodeURIComponent(atob(str).split('').map(function(c) {
       return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
      }).join(''));
  }
    document.write(b64DecodeUnicode(encodedString));

} else{
alert("wrong pass");
  }

}
```

With this code, the only error I am getting is: `Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.`.

I only attempted to fix some of the errors for you so that you can continue with writing your logic.